# Creating White list from ip addresses for Samsung Laser Printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer

I got Samsung 2020-series laser printer and it satisfies my needs in quality, but wireless printing is and has been totally nightmare since first setup.

I got dynamic ip address and it vary from time to time when I connect to my ISP, and that's the problem: The printer needs new setup every time I need wireless printing and that's really the way it shouldn't to make things happen.

I've been looking for some tool to make some kind of "white list" for ip addresses, who are allowed to use my printer over the wireless network, but I really have no idea, where to start. Googling have no effort or clever results any of my searching terms. I graduated as a information technology professional about six months ago but I got no talent to program some kind of tool myseelf.

Printer driver's language is Portugese, and Troubleshooting center -software where I could fix stuff got awful layout, it's slow, and crashes now and then.

Does anyone of Samsung printing wiz got an idea what to do? My current solution is that I plug my printer on USB port, and forget the network option, but now I can't take fully advantage on this product. I could save some space in my computer room, if I could keep my printing machine in my bedroom behind the wall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wireless router should be able to give the printer a fixed IP address. The way to do this depends on the router model.

Log in to the router (as administrator) by typing its IP address into your browser. The login name and password should be in the manual, unless you changed it. Then find where to reserve IP addresses. It will be there somewhere. You will need to specify the printers hardware (MAC) address, and which IP address to assign to it.

With my router (a TP-Link Archer D5) I need to click on the Advanced tab > Network > LAN Settings. There I find the table of reserved addresses, where I can add and remove devices. Something similar will be available in your router.

After doing that, the printer will always get the reserved address, and you should not have a problem.

Your "white list" sounds like a different issue. Some printers have a list of IP addresses, and only those IP addresses can send print jobs to the printer. This can be used in large offices to control access to the printer. However it is unlikely that a low-cost printer like the M2020 supports that, as it is intended for home use.

Comment: Thanks! Have to take a look at the router settings. My printer is low-cost printer for home use only, so there's no option to make any kind of list as a default option.